# How to get data from phpMyAdmin, depending on what difficulty level the user selects

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to get some words for my Hangman game from the database [image: MySQL Database] depending on which difficulty level the user selects [image: difficulty levels] so if the user selects "easy" the only words i want it to select is just the words that have "easy" next to it from the database. right now it selects all the words as you can see in this image --> [image]. this is my difficulty page [image: difficulty]
i hope i explaining this question properly so that everyone can understand me, if you don't understand what i am trying to say please let me know.

Comment: This is simple mysql... Did you try and google? None the less I'll give you a hint, `SELECT ... FROM .... WHERE` <-- It's the where part.

Comment: `SELECT word FROM words_list WHERE difficulty='easy' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;` - All you need to do is add a `WHERE` condition that uses the selected difficulty.

Comment: Thank you very much guys I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
$difficulty = 'hard'; //Value based on user selection
$conn->prepare("SELECT 'word' FROM words_list WHERE difficulty= ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$conn->bind_param("s", $difficulty);
```

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 3):

In your query you should add a `where` clause

```
select word from word_list where difficulty = $difficulty order by  rand() limit 1
```

For this to work you need to pass the selection to `$difficulty`

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate it :)

Comment: you can show your appreciation by choosing an answer and or upvoting if we helped, that's how you give thanks. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308249 for more info

Answer (score 3):

Add `WHERE difficulty = <user input>` to your query like so:

`SELECT word FROM word_list WHERE difficulty = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

The `?` becomes the variable put in by the user when you bind the parameter using prepared statements like you are doing. Don't just put the variable in the string or use PHP string concatenation. Use `$conn->bind_param('s', $user_selection);`.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate it :)